# How to choose offset for tile-encoding function approximation

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have a variety of continuous features and would like to apply tile-encoding function approximation for a reinforcement learning task. I am having difficulty defining the offsets for each feature, and have not been able to determine what offsets should be used. Below are the min-max ranges for my 7 features:

F1: 0 - 0.5

F2: 0 - 25

F3: 0 - 25

F4: (-2) - 2

F5: 0 - 5

F6: (-250) - 250

F7: 0 - 100

Following advice in Sutton (pg 220) http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2018.pdf 
the recommendation is to have 4 x NUM_FEATURES for the number of tiles. So in my example I would have 28 tiles. He then recommended a non-uniform offset for the tiling's, and a good practice is to increment by the first 2k-1 odd integers. If I am understanding this correctly, then my first three offsets would look like this:

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13), (2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26)

Considering Features 1, 4, and 5 are a very small range, it appears most tiles would not even be in the possible range after taking into consideration the offset.

Questions:

1) Should the offsets be normalized by the range?

2) Assuming I use 10 bins for each feature, is there a particular strategy or well-known formula for doing the offsets? Or is it basically domain specific and trial & error?